# How to add PHP strlen to custom field clauses

Tags: php, wordpress, substring

So I'm calling a value from a custom field using the standard: `$key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, key/value, true);`

Id like to limit the characters that are displayed in the value. I'm not great with PHP, I can get my way around wp, but things like this stump me.

This is what makes sense to me, but it's not working:

```
if (strlen($key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, key/value, true)) > 45)
    echo substr($key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, key/value, true), 0, 45) . ' ...';
else
    echo $key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, key/value, true);
```

Any help is, as always, much appreciated!
cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indenting the code and using variables usually makes things clearer.

```
$key  = "mykey";
$val  = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);

if ( strlen( $val ) > 45 ) {
    echo substr( $val, 0, 45 );
} else {
    echo $val;
}
```

You don't really need the condition, just `echo substr( $val, 0, 45 );` will do the same thing

Comment: Thanks adeneo, works perfectly. And I noted the formatting advice.!